# Get Active Directory username from Hyperion Back-end Tables of Shared Services

Tags: hyperion, sharedservices

We are trying retrieve Active Directory usernames from Hyperion Shared Services Back-end Tables. We referred "CSS_GROUP_CACHE_DELTA" table and we observed that column "MEMBER_ID" is stored in OBJECTGUID format and could not find any table which provides ID to Name mappings.

Is there any table/way to retrieve the usernames as is so that users can understand? If there is, your inputs are really valuable to us. We are happy to provide you additional information (if accessible and permitted) for your further investigation.

**Version: Hyperion 11.1.2.3.500**

Thanks a lot in Advance!